# postgreSQL: DELETE by matching row data

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-delete

I have the results of a SELECT statement that I would like to turn around and use to delete the matching rows from a different table with the same data. I don't have the specific details from the SELECT -- just the rows returned.

For example, if I have the tables

```
table_1
name  | value
--------------
Bob   | 5
Ben   | 14
Bev   | 8


table_2
name  | value
--------------
Bob   | 5
Bill  | 2
Biff  | 4
```

And I'm given the results of a SELECT from the first table that returns Bob's row, how can I use that to delete Bob from the second table?

**Edit**
To clarify more what I'm doing, I have a script that is going through several pairs of backup/live tables and finds rows that are new and updated (that's the SELECT part I'm given -- its a change log). Now, I need to delete some of those new rows but all I have to work with is the raw data from the change log and the name of the table. For inserts this isn't a problem:

```
INSERT INTO table_name <row data here>  -- Don't need column names
```

I was hoping DELETE had a similar schema-free way of deleting stuff by matching raw data similar to how an EXCEPT clause works.

Comment: do you want the raw SQL query for this?

Comment: Raw SQL would be ideal but I'm open to other solutions

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for something along these lines:

```
DELETE FROM table_2 WHERE (name, value) IN (
    SELECT name, value FROM table_1
)
```

This searches and delete rows of `table_2` whose `name` and `value` match (at least) a row from `table_1`.

If you have a query that gives you the list of `(name, value)` tuples to delete, you can just replace the subquery with that.

Comment: Is it possible to wildcard the WHERE (name, value) portion to something like WHERE (*)? My script doesn't readily have access to the table internals

Comment: @user2859458: I am unsure what you mean, but `WHERE (*) IN (...)` is not valid SQL.

Comment: @user2859458: What do you mean by "doesn't readily have access to the table internals". If you can Select or in this case Delete, then you can access the table, unless there are column level access requirements (aka *Row-Level Security*).

Comment: Thanks for helping with this guys. The script I'm dealing with can run for multiple tables and is written to be schema agnostic. For inserts this isn't a problem: INSERT INTO table_name <row data> <--No schema data required. But I need to do a DELETE and was hoping there was a way to either pass rows to the WHERE clause or do some other kind of pattern matching to tell DELETE which row I want removed without explicitly notating table columns